# Error occurred during initialization of VM Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP

Tags: java, server, raspberry-pi3, minecraft

Attempting to make a Minecraft server with my Rasberry pi and I the error above when running the command  `java -version`. I have reinstalled java and the same occurs. I have a raspberry pie 3 B+.
Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Which Java package did you install? And what OS does your Pi have?

Comment: Open jpk 11 and raspbian

Comment: If you uninstall 11 and install 8 instead, does it work any better?

Comment: I will try that tomorrow thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per the instructions posted by pi4j https://pi4j.com/documentation/java-installation/

> Luckily there are different suppliers providing ready-made packages of
> the JDK for multiple platforms. But only Azul seems to have one which
> is a perfect fit for Raspberry Pi’s with an ARMv6

So you'd need first to check your board version:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

If it has ARMv6 then you need to substitute your Java

```
$ cd /usr/lib/jvm

$ sudo wget https://cdn.azul.com/zulu-embedded/bin/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf.tar.gz

$ sudo tar -xzvf zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf.tar.gz

$ sudo rm zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf.tar.gz
```

Now update alternatives

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf/bin/java 1

$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf/bin/javac 1
```

Then select the newly installed one

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

And here you go, check your new version

```
$ java -version
```

Comment: OP clearly stated that he has Raspberry PI3, which is not ARMv6